# Why does Azure embed different HTML into a custom UI sign-up form for custom and built-in policies?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

Our company has been using the built-in SignUpOrSignIn policy for a while now. We also use the custom UI feature so we can brand the sign-in experience. We have a page with our logo and an empty `div` element: `<div id="api"></div>`, as required.

We've recently had to move to using the (public preview) custom policies feature, again implementing the [custom UI feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-customize-ui-custom).

But while testing the custom policy, I've noticed that on the sign-up page the code that gets inserted inside the empty `div` is different to that using the built-in policy.

For example, with the built-in policy, the text "Please enter a valid email address." is contained within a `div` with the class `error`, which hides the text from the user until they enter an invalid email address. With the custom policy, this text is contained inside a `div` with class `helpText`, and is displayed as soon as the page is loaded.

The custom policy also sees a lot of extra CSS inserted directly into the `head` of the page, which overrides our custom styling in our CSS file. There are other differences as well.

I followed [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom) to set up the custom policies if that's relevant.

**Why is a different sign-up page being shown when I use the custom policy?** The sign-in page seems to be the same, it's just when I click through to sign up for a new account that the differences appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page UI that is displayed is determined by the content definition.

E.g. In [the custom policy starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack), the **api.selfasserted** content definition that is used for the sign-up page UI is set to the **1.1.0** version:

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted">
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:selfasserted:1.1.0</DataUri>
</ContentDefinition>
```

It might be that the built-in and custom policies are using different page UI versions.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I was using `1.0.0` - changed it to `1.1.0` and it now looks how I expected it to look.